# Layout grids for illustrations?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, illustration, grids, figma

Is it possible to use any kind of layout grids when creating illustrations, and if so, what are their uses?

Edit: A bit of clarification, my questions is towards drawing on a computer (not hand drawing) and if you use e.g column/row based grids for visual balance or rhythm.

Comment: @Tetsujin - I've edited the question to try to remove the personal opinion problem. I think it's still useful and can be answered fairly objectively.

Answer (score 2):

Possible yes, but the usefulness of using grids depends on the kind of illustration, what style is used, or how the artist wants to work; whether sketching by hand first, or using grids in graphics software. Some artists use them, but some don't. Some might even use them when sketching by hand, but not necessarily in graphics software itself.  There is certainly no rule that says you must use grids.

For example: perspective grids can be useful for drawing realistic buildings, rooms, landscapes or three dimensional objects. Isometric grids for simplified perspective. Grids to help draw portraits or characters to help achieve realistic anatomical proportions. A grid system can also be used for copying/enlarging illustrations from a photograph or a sketch, etc.

Comment: I would like to add a point of dissent. I find that having a perspective grid or isometric grid adds nothing of value when you draw on a computer. It adds a lot of value if i sketch by hand though, I also teach people to draw this kind of stuff regularily i also feel that these grids make it harder for you to learn how to do the drawings aswel.

Comment: @joojaa - Actually I agree totally, but I was trying really hard not to voice my personal opinions here. I've added a little edit to the first paragraph to try to clarify.